# Preserving CDATA Editing Xml File using Microsoft Word 2003

Tags: xml, microsoft-word-2003

I have an xml file that I need to edit using **Microsoft Word 2003**. Everything works fine but the CDATA section is lost and is converted to normal html. For example:

```
<Description>
 <![CDATA[
  <i>
 ]]>
</Description>
```

gets converted to:

```
<Description>
 <i>
</Description>
```

I want to fix some typos and grammar in the xml file so I am using this approach.

Is there any way to preserve the CDATA section while editing in MS Word?

Comment: You know, Vim (vim.org) has spell checking capabilities.

Comment: Yes I know but trying to find a solution for MS Word, the person who will edit it is a documenter.